# Oracle dynamic sql, find used tables in query

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Is there any way to find list of used tables in Oracle Dynamic SQL. I need to set limits for using some tables.

Example for dynamic query text:

```
select *
  from Table1 T1
  join Table2 T2
    on T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
 where exists (select 1
          from Table3 T3
         where T1.Col2 = T3.Col2)
```

Result should be: `[Table1, Table2, Table3]`. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that.  You could maybe parse the results from an explain plan call

Comment: Put the query in a string and use regex maye to find the tables after the from and join keywords ?  same idea for the explain output when you filter out the line where `TABLE ACCESS` is in the line..

Comment: Thank you for everyone who helped to solve this problem. I planned to add opportunity to my soft that users can take reports by writing SQL Query by themselves. But the problem is i can't allow to use all tables and all functions.  I think, i should find another way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any way to find list of used tables in Oracle Dynamic SQL".

No. That is, no cast-iron and straightforward way. One of the consequences of dynamic SQL is the increased difficulty of impact analysis.

It is true you might be able to find some table names embedded in literal strings in the source code.

```
select *
from user_source
where lower(text) like '%table1%'
or  lower(text) like '%table2%'
or  lower(text) like '%table3%'
```

Obviously, you'll need to clear up the output to isolate the table names, and maybe to handle false positives on `table17` and `table23`.

However, it is common for dynamic SQL to work on tables whose names are passed as parameter strings at runtime or queried from the data dictionary. It's unlikely you'll be able to catch all of those. Obviously the size of this gap depends on how you use dynamic SQL: maybe you'll be alright.

If your organisation pays for the Tuning and Diagnostics packs you could use [ASH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_1007.htm#REFRN30299) to find the executed SQL IDs, which you can parse to find the involved tables and with luck also divine the code which generated and executed the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Take your string for Dynamic SQL into a SQL SELECT Statement like below to extract the table names contained within the string :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'select *
  from Table1 T1
  join Table2 T2
    on T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
 where exists (select 1
          from Table3 T3
         where T1.Col2 = T3.Col2)' from dual
), t2 as
(
  select level as row_num, regexp_substr(to_char(t.str),'^.*$',1,level,'m') as str
    from t
   connect by level <= length (to_char(t.str)) 
                     - length (replace (to_char(t.str), chr (10))) + 1 
), t3 as
(
select regexp_substr(
           regexp_substr(str,'From[[:space:]].*[[:space:]]',1,1,'i'),
                        '[^ ]+',1,2) as x,
       regexp_substr(
           regexp_substr(str,'Join[[:space:]].*[[:space:]]',1,1,'i'),
                        '[^ ]+',1,2) as y
  from t2 
)
select coalesce(x,y) as "Tables"
  from t3
 where coalesce(x,y) is not null;

Tables
-------
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d075889e1ea846fe765a9e512e7f1353)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The list of tables used by a SQL statement can be generated using `DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT`, a temporary view, and querying `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`.

`DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT` takes care of finding tables referenced by views.  The temporary view and `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` then generate a list of all tables used in the expanded SQL statement.

### Function

```
create or replace function get_dependent_tables_from_sql(p_sql varchar2)
return sys.odcivarchar2list authid current_user is
    v_expanded_sql clob;
    v_tables sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    --Expand the SQL, which will go through all the recursive dependencies.
    dbms_utility.expand_sql_text
    (
        input_sql_text  => p_sql,
        output_sql_text => v_expanded_sql
    );

    --Create a view with the expanded SQL.
    execute immediate
    '
        create or replace view temp_view_for_dependencies as
        select count(*) the_count
        from
        (
        '||v_expanded_sql||'
        )
    ';

    --Find dependencies.
    --(Use execute immediate to simplify compilation privileges.)
    execute immediate
    q'[
        select distinct referenced_owner||'.'||referenced_name
        from dba_dependencies
        where name = 'TEMP_VIEW_FOR_DEPENDENCIES'
            and owner = user
            and referenced_type = 'TABLE'
    ]'
    bulk collect into v_tables;

    return v_tables;
end get_dependent_tables_from_sql;
/
```

### Sample Schema

```
create table table1(col1 number, col2 number);
create table table2(col1 number, col2 number);
create table table3(col1 number, col2 number);
create table table4(col1 number, col2 number);
create table table5(col1 number, col2 number);
create or replace view view1 as select 1 a from dual;
```

### Calling the function

```
select column_value table_name
from table(get_dependent_tables_from_sql(q'[
        select *
        from table1 t1
        --ANSI joins
        join table2 t2
            on t1.col1 = t2.col1
        where exists
        (
            select 1
            --Oracle style joins, views.
            from table3 t3, table4, view1
            where t1.col2 = t3.col2
        )
        --A table that won't be in execution plan.
        and exists (select 1 from table5 where 1 = 2)   
    ]'))
order by 1;

TABLE_NAME
----------
JHELLER.TABLE1
JHELLER.TABLE2
JHELLER.TABLE3
JHELLER.TABLE4
JHELLER.TABLE5
SYS.DUAL
```

### Warnings about other solutions

Be careful of solutions that involve custom SQL parsing.  This is one of those problems that looks deceivingly easy.  You can build a regular expression that works 98% of the time, but it is literally impossible to build a regular expression that works 100% of the time.

Be careful using execution plan solutions.  It's not trivial to trace the execution plan objects back to the tables, like if only an index is used.  And some tables could be used in the query but excluded from the execution plan because of join elimination.